# Firebase adding Child with specific Name / chrash when Name is referennce (to Firebase User) (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I try to make a Registration that automatically creates a child with the Name of the email, but the Program crashed.

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private Firebase firebase;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


firebase.child("new5").setValue(arrayList); 
mDatabase.child("new5").setValue(arrayList);
```

This two Options works perfectly but when i try to make it with the User:

```
 FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
 String userEmail = user.getEmail().toString();   
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,userEmail,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 mDatabase.child(userEmail).setValue(arrayList);
```

The Toast work, but when I add the last line it crash 
Is there any way to solve this Situation or is there a simple way to connect a child created with "push()" with a User ?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What is arrayList? and which type of structure you want?

Comment: it just chrashes .. coudlnt find a error report

Comment: its just a Arraylist with a few integer ... we try to save geodata for each User ... works fine

Comment: When the program crashes, share the error message and stack trace that shows up in your logcat or crash reporting tool. Without that information, you're depending on educated guesses (like the one from Alex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use `userEmail` in the `DatabaseReference` which is not encoded. Firebase does not allow in it's key symbols like `.` (dot). So in order to solve this, you need to encode the email address like this:

> name@email.com -> name@email,com

To achieve this, i recomand you to use the following methid:

```
static String encodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(".", ",");
}
```

And to decode the email, you can use the following method:

```
static String decodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(",", ".");
}
```